# Customizing fixtures suites

Tags: sylius

I created a new fixtures which looks like the default one, when I execute the command `bin/console sylius:fixtures:load` I have an error does not occur all the time:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

```
INSERT INTO sylius_product_translation 
(name, slug, description, meta_keywords, meta_description, short_description, locale, translatable_id) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Input param values:**

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, "en_US", 470]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an empty product translation.
If you could share the fixture code, I could point you to the issue.

Comment: You will find the config below

Comment: Do you run the default suite before the custom one?

Comment: I run only the custom suite

Comment: Then you have to add some basic configuration to it: currency, locale and channel.
Here's the default fixture for shop configuration: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/fixtures/shop_configuration.yaml

Answer (score -1):

```
sylius_fixtures:
    suites:
        custom_default:
            fixtures:
                product_review:
                    options:
                        random: 20

                similar_product_association:
                    options:
                        amount: 3

                fulfilled_order:
                    name: order
                    options:
                        amount: 12
                        channel: 'My_CHANNEL'
                        fulfilled: true

                new_order:
                    name: order
                    options:
                        amount: 8
                        channel: 'My_CHANNEL'

                address:
                    options:
                        random: 4
                        prototype:
                            country_code: CN
```